# module not found: org.grails.plugins#cloud-support;[1.0.7,)

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

I'm attempting to revive an old Grails project (was 2.0.4 when I left it), and I can't get anything to start because the following dependency issue. Can anyone be of assistance?

```
 Downloading: grails-cloud-support-1.0.8.zip.sha1
 :: problems summary ::
 :::: WARNINGS
    module not found: org.grails.plugins#cloud-support;[1.0.7,)
```

and maybe more informative:

```
 | Downloading: grails-test-2.1.1.jar
 :: problems summary ::
 :::: WARNINGS
    module not found: org.grails.plugins#cloud-support;[1.0.7,)
==== grailsPlugins: tried
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#cloud-support;[1.0.7,)!cloud-support.zip:
```

Comment: Is the dependency defined in BuildConfig? Can you try (compile ":cloud-support:1.0.11") as given [here](http://grails.org/plugin/cloud-support)

Comment: or try updating the version no. of any other plugin that depends on cloud support. e.g., the Cloud Foundry plugin.

Comment: or if you can't update the dependency, try something of this sort for the plugin that depends on cloud support.
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ 
compile(':cloud-foundry:1.2.3') {
    excludes 'cloud-support'
  }

Comment: I'll take a look at this later, but I'd suspect that Cloud Foundry could be an issue. I'll paste the entire log to see if that helps.

Comment: I ended up just re-creating the project... had enough old stuff that needed to be ripped out that this was a viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just re-creating the project and added new plugins. I had enough old stuff that needed to be ripped out that this was a viable option.

I'm sure the above comments would have helped, but I'm not able to select that as an answer.